# Why extension allows to override the default Double method?

Tags: swift

We all know that extension can't override. If we try to create a new random class with a method and then try to expand the method we will get an error -
[*click*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OOrT.png).
Surprisingly, if we try to expand the default Double method "round" it overrides. Why?

```
extension Double {
    func round() {
        
    }
}

var pi = 3.14159
pi.round()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for the very reason you gave:

- When *you* create a type with a method, you get an error if you try to redeclare that method in an extension.
- But when *Swift* creates a type, it's in a different module. The compiler doesn't stop you from creating a method in an extension that matches a method in a different module.

Note that this is not an override. It's an "alternative implementation", i.e. an implementation that is different for a different module. But which module's implementation will Swift use? Basically, there's a hole in the language: when it comes time to call this method, there is no way for *you* to say "the one in the other module" vs. "the one in this module". Swift will in fact prefer the one in this module, usually, so you have in effect *replaced* the default implementation of `round` — but not by overriding.

Basically, the best advice is Don't Do That.

Comment: See my https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8010 where I inquire about much the same thing. There's a proposal to do something about it, but it has gone nowhere: https://github.com/jrose-apple/swift-evolution/blob/overridable-members-in-extensions/proposals/nnnn-overridable-members-in-extensions.md